How to make sed "silent" in a vim script?
This vim script make its work
#!/usr/bin/vim
%!sed 's/ .*//'
%!sort -fu
norm dd
% norm $D

The only problem is this message at the end (i have to press ENTER in keyboard)
"20 lines filtered
20 lines filtered
Press ENTER or type command to continue
"

How to simulate ENTER in script? So I can avoid to press manually
I put this at the end of script but don't work
norm <^M>

Checking the problem is sed (wich produce the output), not vim.
How to make sed more quiet?
Using "sed -n" produce an empty output.
Tried with a text with those lines
https://pastebin.com/DU9Rx0SZ

This has nothing to do with sed.  If you filter lines through cat in the same manner, Vim will also notify you that it has filtered a certain number of lines.  Notice how you also get the  same message for the invocation of sort.

Are you running the script with vim -s?  If so, each line should also have : at the start (because that is what you would type, had it been an interactive session). Please update your question with the exact way you run your script.

No, I edit a text file, then invoke script using source command

How to simulate:  xdotool key Return

Thanks, i insert xdotool key  Return in script and..nothing change.

Why are you writing vim "scripts" (which aren't really scripts, they're just a series of vim commands to break out of vim so you can call a bunch of tools, i.e. doing one of the things a shell is designed to do) at all instead of just sed or awk or bash or some other common scripting tool? If you post concise, testable sample input and expected output we can show you how to do whatever it is you need to do using a real scripting tool.

Or, why use external tools when vim has :sort and :s? This question maybe belongs on [vi.se].

Something like :%s/ .*// followed by :sort iu does inside Vi(m) what the first two "filters" (!) do.

Thanks but :%s/ .*// return error in script (extra char), and sort iu produce the same output "20 lines filtered"

This is an XY problem, or in other words "using the wrong tool for the job". Write a regular script and don't abuse vim in a pipeline.

You can create a function in vim and :call it. If the described functionality is something that you need to do often, you can even :map that function to a shortcut. Unlike others who replied, I still think this is better handled inside Vim itself if it is something related to files you open in Vim anyway. If not, then I agree that it is better to create a script or an alias or a shell function, if it is only a couple of commands.

This command generates a file sort.vim, which you can load using :source sort.vim and then call using :silent! call Sortit() or just by pressing Ctrl+T (example): printf ':function Sortit()\n:%%s/ .*//\n:sort iu\n:endfunction\nnmap <silent> <C-t> :silent! call Sortit()<CR>\n' > sort.vim

Also see: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/call-a-vim-function-silently

Literal answer
Use the vim :silent or :silent! to prefix individual commands whose messages should not be output, e.g.:
:silent! %!sort -fu

For the difference between :silent and :silent!, see silent vs. silent! - What is the difference?
A different (correct) approach
Depending on whether the actions from your script are related to files you open in Vim anyway, it is better to either use Vim's own commands :sort and :s, avoiding unnecessary external commands, or create a shell script (or a shell alias, or a shell function) otherwise.
Using Vim function
The following script, sort.vim:
" sort.vim
function Sortit()
  %s/ .*//
  sort iu
  normal dd
  %normal $D
endfunction

nmap <silent> \s :silent! call Sortit()<CR>

can be sourced with :source sort.vim and the function Sortit can be called with :silent! call Sortit() or by pressing \s. Alternatively, the function can be added to $HOME/.vimrc, eliminating the need to source the script manually.
Using shell function
The following file sortit.sh contains the shell function sortit:
# sortit.sh
sortit()
{
    sed 's/ .*//' |
        sort -fu |
        sed '1d;s/.$//'
}

and can be sourced, after which that function can be called in the shell:
$ . ./sortit.sh      # assuming sortit.sh is in current directory
$ cat test.sort
Zed foo  bar
a line
more  test text
Blur
$ sortit < test.sort
Blu
mor
Ze

as with the Vim script, this function can be added to user's $HOME/.profile or a similar file, avoiding the need to source the script.
Edit: Using the sample text from the paste linked in the question:
$ cat test2.sort
dkms-3.0.11-x86_64-1_SBo
  Repo version:  dkms-3.0.12-x86_64-1_SBo
graphviz:
  POTENTIAL UPDATE
  Installed version:  graphviz-9.0.0-x86_64-1_SBo
  Repo version:  graphviz-11.0.0-x86_64-1_SBo
$ sortit < test2.sort
dkms-3.0.11-x86_64-1_SB
graphviz
$

Of course, if you pass -n to sed(1) in the shell function sortit, it will produce no output unless the explicit p command is given, but in this example there is no point. Just don't use that option, but the literal commands from this answer?

I tried it, and my text file return no output, try with those lines https://pastebin.com/DU9Rx0SZ

What did you try exactly? sortit < test2.sort, where test2.sort contains the lines from that paste, returns two lines: first contains dkms-3.0.11-x86_64-1_SB, second graphviz. Same result is obtained when the file is read into vim and \s is used after sourcing sort.vim.

Look https://images2.imgbox.com/7e/c8/YWP3Y5NH_o.jpg

What operating system and shell is this? The answer I gave is valid for POSIX-compliant Unix-like systems.

You are not using the script and the function in the manner given in the answer. Please use the literal commands. You need to save the script in the file sortit.sh and source the shell script with . ./sortit.sh (or in your example . ./sortit - I used the ending .sh to avoid this ambiguity), then use the function with sortit < test.sort (note the lack of ./).

I made it, same thing
